# PHP extend existing class for table insertion/update

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I am curently working on a extended class and still have no ideea if this would be the best way to do it

Let's say the primary class is something like the above (keep in mind the fields from table are more than 2, but for demo purpose I only wrote 2 fields):

```
Class Product () {
    public $id, $product;
    protected $sql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect = Singleton::getconnect();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->connect = null;
    }

    public function insert_product() {
       $this->sql = 'INSERT INTO sh_products (id,product) VALUES (NULL, "'.
          addslashes($this->product) . '")';
       $return_id = $this->connect->mysql_execute($this->sql);
       return $return_id;
    }

    public function update_product() {
       $this->sql = 'UPDATE sh_products SET '.
          'product="' . addslashes($this->product) . '"'. 
          'WHERE id = ' . $this->id;
       $aff_row = $this->connect->mysql_execute($this->sql);
       return $aff_row;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a second table witch stores the prices of the products. The table is `sh_product_service_prices`. 
What is the best way to update the `sh_product table` in the same time with the `sh_product_service_prices`? 
All the user inputs are on the same page but I would not choose to modify the first class but rather create another one that would extent Product class. 
The field structure of sh_product_service_prices looks like:

```
id | idp (product id) | price
```

I would like to use the `update_product()` procedure but in that procedure to add also the price info or something like that ...
But as a second question, when I call the update procedure from Product class I would like to have all fields updated.

Could someone help me with a solution that would not require a change for the first class?

Comment: I'm confused by the last two paragraphs. You said you'd like to use `Product::update_product()` to do additional operations, but then you asked for a solution that would not require changing the first class (I'm assuming you mean `Product`). I don't think it's possible to make the class do more without changing it :/

Comment: I am asking if there could be a solution to have a second class, let's say product_price that would have the update_product() with only the updates for the sh_product_service_prices .. could it be done like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it doesn't really make sense for the new class (let's call it `ProductPrice`) to extend the `Product` class because logically the `Product` class contains a `ProductPrice`. So ideally you would add a `ProductPrice` member variable to the `Product` class and do something like this:

```php
class Product ()
{
    /**
     * @var ProductPrice
     */
    private $price;
    ...
    public function update_product()
    {
        // Product save logic
        ...
        $this->price->save();
    }
}
```

If you absolutely want to have `ProductPrice` extending `Product`, I would stop and really think about your reasons. Having said that, you can call parent methods from the child via the `parent` keyword.

```
class ProductPrice extends Product
{
    public function update_product()
    {
        // ProductPrice update logic goes here
        ...
        // This will call Product::update_product()
        // If you don't include this line, Product::update_product() will NOT be called
        parent::update_product();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was so simple and elegant!